# Can anyone tell me why do experts use \'' in mySql query

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a mySql command as belows, I got it from one of my senior source. Can anyone tell me why he has used \'' ?

```
INSERT INTO `items` (`department`, `category`, `sub_category`, `received_date`, `last_received_date`, `received_quantity`, `last_received_quantity`, `received_unit`, `received_price`, `required_quantity`, `description`, `created_on`, `created_by`, `active`,`grn`,`invoice`) VALUES (\''.test.'\', \''.testcat.'\', \''.testsub.'\', \''.2017-07-13.'\', \''.2017-07-13.'\', \''.20.'\', \''.20.'\', \''.20.'\', \''.200.'\', \''.200.'\', \''.none.'\', \''.11.25.'\', \''.admin.'\', \''.y.'\',\''.22ee.'\',\''.vv33.'\');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an 'escape character'. The SQL would not parse, because it's expecting some text input, which is contained within `'`. It allows the character `'` to literally be inserted in to the string.

edit: Note: *why* it's being used depends on the structure of the database and the type of the column that the data is pointing to, there's not enough information in your original post to provide a more specific answer for this case.